# How to get my Python Morse code-decoder to separate after a word has been translated?

Tags: python, morse-code

When I get my decoder to run I can translate a word from Morse to normal but if I use more than one word it doesn't separate the words, how do I separate the words? Here is my code:

```
code_dict =  {'.-...': '&', '--..--': ',', '....-': '4', '.....': '5',
     '...---...': 'SOS', '-...': 'B', '-..-': 'X', '.-.': 'R',
     '.--': 'W', '..---': '2', '.-': 'A', '..': 'I', '..-.': 'F',
     '.': 'E', '.-..': 'L', '...': 'S', '..-': 'U', '..--..': '?',
     '.----': '1', '-.-': 'K', '-..': 'D', '-....': '6', '-...-': '=',
     '---': 'O', '.--.': 'P', '.-.-.-': '.', '--': 'M', '-.': 'N',
     '....': 'H', '.----.': "'", '...-': 'V', '--...': '7', '-.-.-.': ';',
     '-....-': '-', '..--.-': '_', '-.--.-': ')', '-.-.--': '!', '--.': 'G',
     '--.-': 'Q', '--..': 'Z', '-..-.': '/', '.-.-.': '+', '-.-.': 'C', '---...': ':',
     '-.--': 'Y', '-': 'T', '.--.-.': '@', '...-..-': '$', '.---': 'J', '-----': '0',
     '----.': '9', '.-..-.': '"', '-.--.': '(', '---..': '8', '...--': '3'
     }

def decodeMorse(morseCode):
    results = []
    for item in morseCode.split(' '):
        results.append(code_dict.get(item))
    results = ''.join(results)
    return results.lower()

morseCode = input('Message: ')
print(decodeMorse(morseCode))
```

Edit:

`hello my name is`, is:

```
.... . .-.. .-.. ---  -- -.--  -. .- -- .  .. ...
```

when I run the decoder it gives me `hellomynameis`, I would like it to give me `hello my name is`

Comment: In the original input are words separated by spaces?
Otherwise it is impossible.

If it is, just add an entry in the dict that maps a `' '` to a `' '`.

This is not a python question nontheless, but an algorithmic one

Comment: Yes, for example, hello is: .... . .-.. .-.. ---

Comment: Wait, words arent seperated but characters are

Comment: @Hunter Can you explain your problem a little more? Use an example.

Comment: Morse code (at least standard Morse code) doesn't have spaces; historically the human operator figured out where the spaces are by simply recognizing the words.  Doing this in software (by comparing subsets of the string to an English dictionary, and possibly resolving ambiguities by doing NLP to figure out what version makes a more grammatical sentence) is doable but nontrivial; it's a SIGNIFICANTLY harder problem than what you've tackled so far.

Comment: If characters rather than words are separated by a space, then you are asking rather too much and you need to change the specification so that it is words that are separated by a space (or a double-space so that you can still recognize individual characters). Wouldn't that make more sense?

Comment: Ok but I shall go with @Leemosh answer to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example made it not possible. You are not giving any other separator than a `space` in the input and so you are not able to divide words in any way.

Your solution is to give your input a word separator (for example    (double space), then split with `.split("  ")` and loop tru words).

Other solution might be `nltk` library, which might have some special functions for that - but here I'm just guessing.